# Control arrow key to jump to the next word

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, spaces, expose

I have OS X 10.6.8 and I run MS Word:Mac 2011.  I programmed the keyboard to allow me to jump from word to word in a document by hitting <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow key</kbd>.  This makes word processing much faster.  However, I lost this ability after an update some time ago.  Now, when I hit  <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow key</kbd> OS X cycles through what I believe are Spaces on my desktop.

This is hugely annoying and I have no interest in using Spaces.  I am perfectly happy to switch between apps using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  How do I go back to being able to use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow key</kbd> to navigate in a document in MS Word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

It seems like OS X automatically re-assigns ⌥→ and ⌥← to jump one word forward/backward, as soon as you disable the 'switching space' shortcuts in the Mission Control.

System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts and uncheck the Mission Control shortcuts

[image]

Comment: Only the left arrow is working, the right one do nothing after that

Answer (score 9):

To disable the shortcut for switching to spaces go to the keyboard shortcuts tab of the keyboard preferences pane. Select Mission Control on the left and then un-check the 'Move left/right a space' options.

Answer (score 3):

To move from word to word, you must use Option + arrow keys

Comment: That definitely didn't used to be the case.

Comment: Is there a way to change it to ctrl?